# java.util.concurrent.CancellationException while saving Datastore Entities

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, import-from-excel

I'm trying to process a big excel file with more than 20K rows. Each row should be saved as an Entity in Datastore. First, I get the excel file in my servlet using the Blobstore and then I queue a task using the Task Queue service. This task, reads the excel file, convert each line in an Entity and store it. As I said before, Excel file could have more than 20K rows. After a while I get this exception:

```
com.xxx.xxx.ProcessBlob doPost: |POST|ProcessBlob|Exception:Task was cancelled.|Msg:Task was cancelled.|Stack:java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.

    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.cancellationExceptionWithCause(AbstractFuture.java:796)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:475)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:381)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:85)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.TimedFuture.get(TimedFuture.java:42)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:63)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:88)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$ReorderingMultiFuture.get(Batcher.java:131)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:88)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:88)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:88)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:75)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:35)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:56)
    at com.xxx.xxx.xxx.createEntity(EntityService.java:87)
    at com.xxx.xxx.ProcessBlob.doPost(ProcessBlob.java:145)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:254)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:527)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Future.cancel() was called.
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.cancel(AbstractFuture.java:514)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.TimedFuture.cancel(TimedFuture.java:85)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.cancel(ForwardingFuture.java:48)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.cancel(ApiProxyImpl.java:553)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestManager.cancelPendingAsyncFutures(RequestManager.java:626)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestManager.sendDeadline(RequestManager.java:399)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.RequestManager.sendDeadline(RequestManager.java:357)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.CloneControllerImpl.sendDeadline(CloneControllerImpl.java:201)
    at com.google.apphosting.sandbox.ModelClonePb$CloneController$ServiceParameters$3.handleRequest(ModelClonePb.java:1166)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerInternalContext.runRpcInApplication(RpcServerInternalContext.java:558)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerChannel$1.run(RpcServerChannel.java:871)
    at com.google.tracing.LocalTraceSpanRunnable.run(LocalTraceSpanRunnable.java:56)
    at com.google.tracing.LocalTraceSpanBuilder.internalContinueSpan(LocalTraceSpanBuilder.java:626)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerChannel.startRpc(RpcServerChannel.java:837)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerChannel.receivedMessage(RpcServerChannel.java:594)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerChannel.access$2700(RpcServerChannel.java:164)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.server.RpcServerChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcServerChannel.java:2365)
    at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:457)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$ServerAdapter.receivedMessage(UdrpcTransport.java:707)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.dispatchPacket(UdrpcTransport.java:384)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.readPackets(UdrpcTransport.java:283)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$1.run(UdrpcTransport.java:100)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:594)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:1011)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:892)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInfo.java:161)
    at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl$WorkerThread.run(EventManagerImpl.java:1879)
```

Another "weird" thing is that, seeing the logs for the requests, the parameters "ms" and "cpu_ms" are nearly the same when it drops that exception. Maybe I'm going above the AppEngine limits or timeout limits?

```
[02/Mar/2015:21:11:32 -0800] "POST /tasks/ProcessBlob HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://xxx.appspot.com/upload" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "xxx.appspot.com" ms=599492 cpu_ms=32522 queue_name=default task_name=xxx instance=xxx app_engine_release=1.9.18

[02/Mar/2015:23:21:55 -0800] "POST /tasks/ProcessBlob HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://xxx.appspot.com/upload" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "xxx.appspot.com" ms=599420 cpu_ms=33262 queue_name=default task_name=xxx instance=xxx app_engine_release=1.9.18
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you faced Task Queue limits, 599949ms == 10 minutes. As per doc:

> Tasks targeted at an automatic scaled module must finish execution
>   within 10 minutes. If you have tasks that require more time or
>   computing resources, they can be sent to manual or basic scaling
>   modules, where they can run up to 24 hours.

See docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/overview-push#task_deadlines

I suggest to split task into few smaller tasks, say one task per 1000 records, maybe smaller