# GAE Getting lots of CancellationException for Task Queue DataStore call

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Java GAE instance that runs TaskQueue jobs.  In the last 48 hours I have been getting lots of CancellationException errors (about 36 in a 24 hour period).

The error always occurs on a DataStore query to a particular table.  The query is on an indexed column, projectId,and the query is a composite OR (i.e. projectId = -1 or projectId = 23).  The entire table in question has 96 records and any one query will pull back 20 records at most.

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting these problems

Thanks
Paul

**Update:** Sorry my mistake, this isn't part of a Task Queue call it is the code that sets up the task queue call.  The time the call took is on average about 59.5 secs (thanks for pointing that out Alex).  Looking at the trace (thanks Alex) it seems that the delay is in the datastore call.  It can be as quick as 21ms or over 59000ms, which is way to long.  I just checked the logs again and there hasn't been any of those exceptions in the last 24 hours so this might be a 48 hour glitch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Understanding "CancellationException: Task was cancelled" error while doing a Google Datastore query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069779/understanding-cancellationexception-task-was-cancelled-error-while-doing-a-go)

Based on this question, it sounds like `CancellationException` means that you are hitting the 10-minute timeout that TaskQueue Jobs have to complete execution.

Do your logs show how long these requests are running for before they throw an exception (for example stackdriver shows that this deferred task ran for 902ms)?

[image]

Querying a table of 96 records should be fine, but it's hard to be certain without being able to see what the code of your task looks like.

You could split your task up into smaller 'sub-tasks' and have sub-task launch the next sub-task before returning.

EDIT: you could also try going here https://console.cloud.google.com/traces/traces to see a break down of where your request is spending its time

[image]

Comment: Hi, it doesn't show how long it was running for put this query is right near the beginning of the code.  I can't split this up because this query is what it runs to decide what need to happen.  It's as though the fault is in the datastore and it is freezing up, but I can't see anything along those lines

Comment: I added 2 screenshots. what does https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer show for the total run time for the request? Also what do you see in the trace reports

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the extra information it's really helpful (I never noticed the time there before and didn't know about the trace screen).  Please see update above.

Comment: So it sounds like it's just hanging and then hitting the 60sec timeout. This article talks about it and has some tips (in particular see the section about warmup requests): https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors It's hard to say why it's hanging, could be a variety of things. I have had other issues with GAE in the past where a memory leak in some lower-level library would cause all requests running on an instance to hang until they hit their timeouts.

Comment: Hi Alex, yeah it does sound a bit like a one (or 48) off problem.  Maybe, if it could be a memory leak, I'll try a re-deploy to see if that fixed.  I wish there was some easy way to reset the system to overcome these problems.  Thanks for your insight and help